# Error when building igraph from source

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to build the `igraph` R package from source. The source code was downloaded from the [official igraph site](http://igraph.org/nightly/get/r/igraph_1.0.1.tar.gz). While trying to build a package for this, using the `install` function from `devtools` (i.e., `install("igraph")`), I get the following error:

```
In file included from dqueue.c:29:0:

   dqueue.pmt:59:35: error: unknown type name 'TYPE'
   dqueue.pmt:83:39: error: unknown type name 'TYPE'
   dqueue.pmt:103:52: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'TYPE' [enabled by default]
   dqueue.pmt:103:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]
   dqueue.pmt:103:71: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
   dqueue.pmt:119:39: error: unknown type name 'TYPE'
   dqueue.pmt:139:45: error: unknown type name 'TYPE'
   dqueue.pmt:156:46: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'TYPE' [enabled by default]
   dqueue.pmt:156:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]
   dqueue.pmt:156:65: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
   dqueue.pmt:180:1: error: unknown type name 'BASE'
   dqueue.pmt:180:42: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'TYPE' [enabled by default]
   dqueue.pmt:180:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]
   dqueue.pmt:180:61: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
   dqueue.pmt:198:1: error: unknown type name 'BASE'
   dqueue.pmt:198:42: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'TYPE' [enabled by default]
   dqueue.pmt:198:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]
   dqueue.pmt:198:61: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
   dqueue.pmt:219:1: error: unknown type name 'BASE'
   dqueue.pmt:219:35: error: unknown type name 'TYPE'
   dqueue.pmt:247:1: error: unknown type name 'BASE'
   dqueue.pmt:247:40: error: unknown type name 'TYPE'
   dqueue.pmt:282:35: error: unknown type name 'TYPE'
   dqueue.pmt:282:59: error: unknown type name 'BASE'
   dqueue.pmt:372:1: error: unknown type name 'BASE'
   dqueue.pmt:372:38: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'TYPE' [enabled by default]
   dqueue.pmt:372:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]
   dqueue.pmt:372:58: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
make: *** [dqueue.o] Error 1
    Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="riyerGraph.dll" SHLIB_LIBADD='$(FLIBS)' ' had status 2
   ERROR: compilation failed for package 'igraph'
```

Now, the file dqueue.c is available in the git rep for `igraph` at the following location: [dqueue.c](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/a98fccd3fb2a9f67551a09d4159ef268ee62c658/src/dqueue.c).

The header file dqueue_pmt.h does contain the macros for type, which are somehow not visible in dqueue.pmt file.

What I am missing?

Note: I am installing this package from the source I downloaded and not from the package that is already available online.

Comment: Where did you get the `install` command? from within R or out of R? Maybe you should use the `install.packages` function in R.

Comment: install.packages() tries to download the package from CRAN. install(), on the other hand can be used for building your own packages from source.(refer to this article [link]( http://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/ ). I have edited my post to reflect the exact error that I am getting during build. Hope that cleared your doubt.

Comment: @Rohit - do you _need_ to build `igraph` from source? Binaries [exist on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/index.html), so if you don't need to build it, then try `install.packages('igraph')`, as Ven Yao suggested.

Comment: The version on CRAN is also 1.0.1 - perhaps they're identical anyway (unless you're modifying the source yourself).

Comment: exactly, I wish to modify the source.